# Javascript : Loading screen cover the site for every item check

Tags: javascript, html, css, checkbox

Sorry I am new to javascript. I just wanted to know can I make a javascript function for a check-box. When the user checks the check-box it will show the loading screen for 1 or 2 seconds.

Concept i looking for : 
http://hibbard.eu/blog/pages/block_ui_with_jquery/

Comment: try to read setTimeout function of javascript. this will give you an idea on how to create a thread like functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the JavaScript `setTimeout` property.  Call a function to show the cover, then, after 2 seconds, fun another function to remove it.

### [JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ianhazzard/9b2sn4uc/6/).